# Is it possible to pass a parameter into the handler for a c timer?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I'm writing a multithreaded program that uses a timer on each thread. The handler for each should trigger a flag specific to that thread. However, I'm not sure how to identify which timer the signal came from. I'm using `setitimer`. I want the signal to simulate an interrupt for a running process so I'm having the thread run an arbitrary task until it gets the flag to exit and keep going. Alternatively to passing in a parameter, is there any way of getting the signal number that gets passed to the handler before you start the timer?

edit: running code on linux machine.

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: linux debian but this is for an OS instructor I know uses fedora. So something not distro specific would be preferred(though if I'm not mistaken this is all posix libraries).

Comment: Still something you should mention in the question. I would have guessed Windows and been wrong. Sure enough, the function name you gave is `setitimer` instead of `settimer`. You read what you're familiar with.

Comment: I'm less familiar programming c in windows actually. I've run the setitimer function in linux already and it works fine. I got example code for it from here(a section from a book on linux programming): http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23618&seqNum=14

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Linux, I suggest using `timerfd_create()` instead of `setitimer()`.  That will let you create lots of timers, multiplex them using `select()` or `epoll_wait()`, and avoid the use of signals which are a bit tricky to get completely right.

Comment: After searching through a few examples and man pages let me see if I have the story here. create returns a file descriptor that references the timer. settime will start the timer. epoll_wait will take the file descriptor and wait until the timer expires at which point I can trigger my interrupt flag and continue execution. Does that seem to be on the right track?